# filter multiple values in single column in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter

How could i return couple name:[apple, orange, carrot]
[http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/QHtD8/2/][1](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/QHtD8/2/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.products = [
        {id:"1",type:"fruit"},
        {id:"2",type:"meat"},
        {id:"3",type:"drink"},
        {id:"4",type:"vegetable"},
        {id:"5",type:"dairy"}
    ];

    $scope.fruitOrVeg = function(product){
        return product.name == ['1','4','5'];
    };
```

Thank you very much

Comment: fiddle not working

Comment: could not find your fiddle, it says 404!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your template, to call function:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in products | filter:fruitOrVeg()">{{item.name}}</li>
```

and filter function, return new function

```
$scope.fruitOrVeg = function() {
return function(item) {
  return ['1', '4', '5'].indexOf(item.id) > -1;
}
```

};

Added [JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/marconak/yp9a64yj/)

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, i changed the array to make it more clear, i need to filter certain id such as [1,3,5] it's radom

Comment: Updated. Check fiddler

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [AngularJS custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

```
app.filter('filterByFruitOrVeg', function() {
   return function(array) {
       arr = arr.filter(payment, function(objectInArray) {
            return objectInArray.type === 'fruit' || objectInArray.type === 'vegetable';        
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, i changed the array to make it more clear, i need to filter certain id such as [1,3,5] it's radom

Comment: This will give you an array of filtered objects which you could iterate to get the ids.